# SwiftUI Button not being registered properly

Tags: swift, uibutton, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui

Ok so basically I was able to follow a tutorial and create this sleek Navigation Bar below:

[image]

Here's a snippet of how programmed that in swiftui:

```
NavigationView {

        HStack{

            Spacer()

            NavigationLink(destination: Main(), tag: 1, selection: ($selected)) {

                Button(action: {
                    self.selected = 1
                }) {
                    Image("NewsTab").foregroundColor(self.selected == 1 ? .black : .white).padding(.horizontal).onTapGesture {
                        print("wtf")
                    }
                }
            }
                Spacer(minLength: 15)
                Button(action: {
                    self.selected = 0
                }) {
                    Image("Home").foregroundColor(self.selected == 1 ? .black : .white).padding(.horizontal)
                }

                Spacer(minLength: 15)
                Button(action: {
                    self.selected = 2
                }) {
                    Image("Search").foregroundColor(self.selected == 1 ? .black : .white).padding(.horizontal)
                }
            Spacer()
    }
    .animation(.interactiveSpring(response: 0.6, dampingFraction: 0.6, blendDuration: 0.6))
}
```

Just when I thought that the NavigationLink feature was going to work (I'm only using NavigationLink for the 'NewsTab' button), the buttons just remain stagnant and don't perform the action they're supposed to (they're supposed to redirect to a different page by the way just in case you're wondering, not sure if that means anything).

Please let me know what I should try out! Anything helps:)

Comment: Each of those buttons goes to the same destination which is `Main()` they don't all go to different ones.  Also reading the documentation only the one where selection matches tags should actually work which would be the first ones.

Answer (score 0):

Here is fixed variant. Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

```
NavigationView {
    HStack{
        Spacer()
        Button(action: {
            self.selected = 1
        }) {
            Image("NewsTab")
                .foregroundColor(self.selected == 1 ? .black : .white).padding(.horizontal)
        }
        .background(NavigationLink(destination: Text("Main1"), tag: 1, selection: $selected) {
            EmptyView() })

        Spacer(minLength: 15)
        Button(action: {
            self.selected = 0
        }) {
            Image("Home")
                .foregroundColor(self.selected == 0 ? .black : .white).padding(.horizontal)
        }
        .background(NavigationLink(destination: Text("Main2"), tag: 0, selection: $selected) {
            EmptyView() })

        Spacer(minLength: 15)
        Button(action: {
            self.selected = 2
        }) {
            Image("Search")
                .foregroundColor(self.selected == 2 ? .black : .white).padding(.horizontal)
        }
        .background(NavigationLink(destination: Text("Main3"), tag: 2, selection: $selected) {
            EmptyView() })
        Spacer()
    }
    .animation(.interactiveSpring(response: 0.6, dampingFraction: 0.6, blendDuration: 0.6))
}
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the quick reply but the buttons still aren't clicking properly. Nothing happening when we're trying to go to a different View. The goal of the button is to serve as a navbar that goes to different pages when each of the buttons is clicked. As of right now when we click the buttons in the simulator it doesn’t show the click and it doesn’t go to the desired page.

Comment: Show how you have changed your code to the suggestion of this answer because you probably still have the same kind of error in the new code.